# Jekyll serve watch error - Windows

Tags: jekyll

Currently running on Windows, with Ruby 1.9.3-p545 and DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe.

I can run serve fine, but as soon as I go to run serve watch I get the following output from the *Windows command prompt:

```
C:\Ruby>jekyll serve --watch
←[33mConfiguration file: none←[0m
        Source: C:/Ruby
   Destination: C:/Ruby/_site
  Generating... done.
Auto-regeneration: enabled
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:207:in `load_dependent_adapter'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:33:in `load_dependent_adapter'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:198:in `usable?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:25:in `usable?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:57:in `block in select_and_initialize'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in `each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in `select_and_initialize'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:283:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:52:in `start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:56:in `watch'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:8:in `process'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/bin/jekyll:97:in `
block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:155:in `run'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:422:in `run_active_command'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:66:in `run!'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:12:in `run!'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/i
mport.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to install this gem on windows for the ability to watch:

```
gem install wdm
```

But if you already have a said gem file within your website root then add this to the gem:

```
require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i
```